# Highlighting the first repeating loop element in django

Tags: python, django, jinja2

Please tell me how to select only the first repeating element of the cycle in Jinja django?

```html
<table id="{{el.slug}}_table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm " cellspacing="0" width="100%" >
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>expand</th>
                    <th>Тип алерта </th>
                    <th>hostname</th>
                    <th>username</th>
                    <th>message</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                  </tr>
                  
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  
                  {% regroup alerts|dictsort:"username" by username as alrt %}
                  {% for all in alrt %}
                  
                    {% for ell in all.list %}
                     
                      {% if el.title == ell.title  %}
                        {% if forloop.first %}
                        <tr class="table-primary">
                          <td class="row1">+</td>
                          <td class="{{ rowcolors }}">{{ell.title}}</td>
                          <td>{{ell.hostname}}</td>
                          <td>{{ell.username}}</td>
                          <td>{{ell.message}}</td>
                          <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bug" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></i></a></td>
                        </tr>
                        {% else %}
                        <tr class="table-light">
                          <td class="row2">+</td>
                          <td class="{{ rowcolors }}">{{ell.title}}</td>
                          <td>{{ell.hostname}}</td>
                          <td>{{ell.username}}</td>
                          <td>{{ell.message}}</td>
                          <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bug" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></i></a></td>
                        </tr>
                        {% endif %}
                      {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                  {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

At the moment, it turned out to select only the first element in the loop, and you need the first repeating one

Answer (score 0):

First, all what you need `{% ifchanged %}` - in documentation, here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged

Secondly, I am not really sure, what you want to do.

Thirdly, I add `{% cycle %}` to made you code a little bit better.

```
<tbody>
...... some staff here              
    {% for all in alrt %}
        {% for ell in all.list %}
            {% ifchanged el.title %}
                <tr class="table-primary">
                   <td class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %}">+</td>
                   ...... some staff here
                </tr>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

By the way, if you use russian in your templates, try to wrap it in trans, it can be better in future:

```
<th>{% trans 'Тип алерта ' %}</th>
```